# CodeIgniter - Display User Account details in a Form input from database

Tags: php, sql, database, codeigniter

Im new to codeigniter and still getting to grips..
I have a user logging into their dashboard, and they can enter their account page.. what i want is to have the account page displaying their details (username, email etc) in a form input (which i will then add update functionality)..

with my current code i am getting two errors when trying to display the data.. an undefined variable for 'results' and an 'invalid argument supplied foreach()' ..thanks in advance if someone can point me in the right direction

**My Controller**

```html
<?php

class Account extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Account_model');
    }
    public function view()
    {
        $data['results'] = $this->Account_model->get_users();
        $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
        $this->load->view('account',$data);
    }
}
```

**My Model**

```html
<?php

    class Account_model extends CI_Model
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->load->database();
        }
        public function get_users()
        {
            $sql = "SELECT id, username, email FROM users ";
            $query = $this->db->query( $sql );
            return $query->result();
        }
    }
```

**My View**

```html
<?php
  foreach ($results as $result)
  {?>
    <label>Username : </label>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $result->id;?>" />
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $result->username;?>" />
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $result->email;?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is because your query did not return any results. So when you try on your view to do a foreach in a variable that is not an array it will give you this error.

Make sure you first verify if you have a valid query then you try to loop. On your view you can do:

```
if(!empty($results)) {
// your loop
}
```

As for your queries I advise you to use the c[odeigniter query builder](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html)

Comment: I have removed the errors with your advice however i cant figure out the query to display the details of the current logged in user

Comment: The query you have returns data from all your users. If that is empty you don't have any records in you database. As for a login you should collect a password and an id that could be an email for instance and in your querywhere email = ... and password = ...

Answer (score 0):

```
You can Use The below Example above...
```

Model: user.php

```
 <?php
 class User extends CI_Model {
public function info(){
 //Loading Database
 $this->load->database();
 //Run Query in Database
 $query=$this->db->get('users');
 return $query->result();
 }
}
 ?>
```

Controller: blog.php

```
  <?php
 defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

 class Blog extends CI_Controller {

  public function index()
    {
      $this->load->model('user');
     $data['result']= $this->user->info();
    $this->load->view('welcome_user',$data);
        } 
      }
```

Views:welcome_user.php

```
  <html>
 <head>
 <title>Codeigniter Controller Examples--codenair.com</title>
 </head>
 <h1>User List's</h1>
<table cellspacing="0" border="1">
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>UserName</th>
<th>Email</th>
 </tr>

<?php foreach($result as $row){?>
  <tr>
  <td><?php echo $row->id;?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row->username;?></td>
 <td><?php echo $row->email;?></td>
</tr>
<?php }?>
 </table>
```

Comment: this runs the invalid argument foreach loop and also undefined variable of result

Answer (score 0):

```
      Try This Codes and Print Out Result array. let me know.. 

      <?php
         defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

      class Blog extends CI_Controller {

       public function index()
      {
         $this->load->model('user');
       $data['result']= $this->user->info();
       print_r($data);
            } 
         }
```

Comment: this returns the undefined variable 'data' .. ive also noticed your code is to print the query results, what i need is to have the results shown within form inputs

Comment: I keep running into undefined variable errors even though i have clearly defined the variable

Answer (score 0):

```
      $loggeduser=$this->session->userdata('username');
      $query= $this->db->query("SELECT*FROM users WHERE username='$loggeduser'");
```

//try this to display the current logged user info..